# Q.How to Retrieve File/Image from Database And Display in JSP web page using Hibernate , MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I need a code that can help me to retrieve my image/file from Mysql database and also display it on the webpage(.jsp) by using HIbernate and Servlet JSP. Q.How to Retrieve File/Image from Database And Display in JSP web page using Hibernate , MySQL Database?, Here's My Code...

```
`/**Employee and Login Registration*/

private void saveEmp(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {        
Employee emp = new Employee();  
Part part = request.getPart("image");
InputStream is = null;

if(part != null) {
    is = part.getInputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read();
    emp.setImage(data);     
            
boolean status = MainServices.saveEmp(emp);
        if(status)
        {
            MainServices.saveLoginData(login);
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Form Submitted Successfully...");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("adminHome.jsp").include(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("msg","Email or Mobile Number is already Registered with us....");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("empForm.jsp").include(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the unstated version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) read Joe Celko's books about databases (and specifically what *not* to do with them) (2) ask this question on StackOverflow, where you have a higher chance of receiving an answer 

Comment: Okay Thankyou Sir